# React Native 5.x passing parameter working example

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I'm studying react native version 5 and I would need a short but working example of two `files.js`, for example `App.js` and `Receiver.js` where:

- in **App.js** you can insert a text through Text Input
- in **Receiver.js** it receives and shows the text inserted once have been passed as state and parameter by the previous page.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should look at the "How to ask a question" link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Code that you have tried and a sample product would help https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the title is misleading. needs to be updated to `react-navigation` v5.

Answer (score 0):

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {

    state = {
        username: 'demo'
    };

    render() { 
     return (
      <Text style={Style.label}>User Name</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={Style.input}
        placeholder="UserName"
        onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({username: value})}
        value={this.state.username}
      />

    <Button
        title="LOGIN"
        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Receiver", {username: this.state.username}) }
    />
    );
  }
}
```

Receiver.js

```
export default class Receiver extends Component {

    render() { 
     const { username} = this.props.route.params;
    return (
     <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>User Name: {username}</Text>      
    </View>
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's React Navigation 5.x https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 0):

A small suggestion: Read the official document before beginning.✌️
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: I already done it, but i still have problems, i don't know why

Comment: Please add your code so that the viewers can point out your mistakes and suggest the right solution.